# How to get the last message in a thread SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, `listhdthreads` and `listhdmessages`.  The `listhdthreads` is the parent table, and each thread has messages in it as children.

```
CREATE TABLE `listhdthreads` (
  `idx` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fromUser` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `respondingUser` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `attachments` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `customerId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `locationId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `areaId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `assetId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `projectId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contactId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `priority` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `createdAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ddGroup` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idx`)
)
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE `listhdmessages` (
  `idx` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parentThreadId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `createdAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `sendingUser` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `text` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `adminMessage` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
  `updatedAt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idx`),
  KEY `parentId` (`parentThreadId`),
  CONSTRAINT `listhdmessages_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`parentThreadId`) REFERENCES `listhdthreads` (`idx`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

Now I have this current query which populates a tabl with all the threads and I want to include the last time a message was sent (which I already have), and the content of the last message itself (this is what I need help with).

The current query as it stands is this (removed unnecessary columns selected)

```
SELECT MAX(m.createdAt) as latestMessage,
FROM listhdthreads as hd 
LEFT JOIN listhdmessages m ON hd.idx = m.parentThreadId 
LEFT JOIN listcustomers c ON hd.customerId = c.idx 
LEFT JOIN listlocations l ON hd.locationId = l.idx 
LEFT JOIN listprojects lp ON hd.projectId = lp.idx
LEFT JOIN listusers lu ON hd.contactId = lu.idx 
LEFT JOIN listusers lus ON hd.fromUser = lus.idx 
LEFT JOIN listusers lusu ON hd.respondingUser = lusu.idx
LEFT JOIN deschdtitles t ON hd.title = t.idx 
LEFT JOIN deschdpriorities p ON hd.priority = p.idx 
LEFT JOIN deschdstatus s ON hd.status = s.idx 
LEFT JOIN helpmessageparticipants hmp ON hd.idx = hmp.parentThreadId
GROUP BY hd.idx
```

I am at a loss with trying to get get the latest message itself.  How can I go about that?  I am using MySQL 5.6.

EDIT:  Sorry, I forgot to include the group by which is necessary for the rest of the query to work right.  That's what is giving me a headache.

Edit 2:  Figured it out.  Turned my initial query into a subquery that I just order by in such a way that my top row of each thread is exactly what I want, and then group by outside of it.

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT hd.idx, hd.ddGroup, c.name as customer, IF(hd.locationId=-1,"None",l.name) as location, CONCAT(lu.firstname, ' ', lu.lastname) as contactId, t.title, lp.number, 
UPPER(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(lus.firstname,1,1), SUBSTRING(lus.lastname,1,1))) as createdBy, IF(hd.respondingUser=-1,"---",UPPER(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(lusu.firstname,1,1), SUBSTRING(lusu.lastname,1,1)))) as forUser,
p.priority,s.status,hd.customerId,hd.locationId,hd.areaId,hd.assetId,hd.projectId,
m.createdAt as latestMessage, m.text as LastMessage
FROM listhdthreads as hd 
LEFT JOIN listhdmessages m ON hd.idx = m.parentThreadId 
LEFT JOIN listcustomers c ON hd.customerId = c.idx 
LEFT JOIN listlocations l ON hd.locationId = l.idx 
LEFT JOIN listprojects lp ON hd.projectId = lp.idx
LEFT JOIN listusers lu ON hd.contactId = lu.idx 
LEFT JOIN listusers lus ON hd.fromUser = lus.idx 
LEFT JOIN listusers lusu ON hd.respondingUser = lusu.idx
LEFT JOIN deschdtitles t ON hd.title = t.idx 
LEFT JOIN deschdpriorities p ON hd.priority = p.idx 
LEFT JOIN deschdstatus s ON hd.status = s.idx 
LEFT JOIN helpmessageparticipants hmp ON hd.idx = hmp.parentThreadId
ORDER BY hd.idx, m.createdAt DESC) as t
GROUP BY t.idx
```

Comment: `select * from .... order by m.createdAt desc limit 1`

Comment: I forgot at the end of the query I had a GROUP BY hd.idx which makes it a little more complicated.

Comment: Could you please add sample data and expected output ? if possible then please add http://www.sqlfiddle.com/ fiddle

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c417d    This just has as single thread iwth the messages.  My desired output is to have thread idx, the timestamp of the latest message, and the message content itself.  I dropped all other tables as they're not necessary.  So the output would be idx 100004, createdAt 2019-05-28 15:52:39, text 'Perfect. Thanks'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery in the ON clause. In the subquery you get the last (MAX) idx of messages from the thread.

```
SELECT hd.*, m.* -- select columns you need
FROM listhdthreads as hd 
LEFT JOIN listhdmessages m ON m.idx = (
    SELECT MAX(mmax.idx)
    FROM listhdmessages mmax
    WHERE mmax.parentThreadId = hd.idx
)
-- JOIN more tables
```

It is better and simpler to use the AUTO_INCREMENT column than `createdAt`. The fact that `createdAt` is not UNIQUE, and two messages from the same thread can be posted at the same second, is reason enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT m.createdAt as latestMessage
FROM listhdthreads as hd
LEFT JOIN listhdmessages m ON hd.idx = m.parentThreadId
...
GROUP BY m.parentThreadId
ORDER BY m.createdAt DESC LIMIT 1
```

OR

```
SELECT hd.idx, m.createdAt as latestMessage
FROM listhdthreads as hd
LEFT JOIN listhdmessages m ON hd.idx = m.parentThreadId
...
GROUP BY hd.idx, m.createdAt
ORDER BY m.createdAt DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I forgot to include the `GROUP BY hd.idx` at the end of the query which makes it a little more complicated.  I think I need a subquery?  Not sure.

Comment: from that i couldn't know which columns to group by as the case may be...if you need to `GROUP BY hd.idx` then you need to select the columns that were grouped

Comment: the other joins are for other entities to include.  This is like a messaging system about the whole heirarchy of the customers and vendors we interact with along with usernames of the people making the mesagehowever you can ignore them all to be honest since they're all essentially optionals.

Comment: @bjk116 i made some edit on the answer you could try that out

Comment: That only returns the very latest thread but it does include the last message of said thread so it's promising.  Somehow need to tweak it.